# How does server communicate with database in general?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, mongodb

Im still new to server and manipulate data. I wonder if someone can explain the practical ways to modify data from database upon client's request in general (nosql or sql).

In Mongodb, for example, database has something like:

```
{_id: 1, actual:2, expect:10}
{_id: 2, actual:4, expect:10}
{_id: 3, actual:6, expect:10}
```

If I want to send

```
percent = actual / expect
```

back to client, how server should handle this request?

Comment: What does "server" refer to in this case? And what is the client?

Comment: In general, you establish a connection, send a request and receive a response. Specifics are system dependant.  I suggest you read some documentation / tutorials for the specific DBMS you are interested in.

Comment: *"in general (nosql or sql)"* There is no answer "in general," other than to say "you write code," because the question is very broad and it is unclear what exactly you are asking.  Your database, your programming language, and your framework all bring their own peculiarities into the mix.